# How to track/handle changes made by other users to source contorl shared emf resource

Tags: eclipse, model, eclipse-emf

Our project saves the model in xml resource file. The xml resource tags get listed as nodes in project explorer. This project is part of source control and been worked upon by multiple users. I am able to handle all enotifications and take appropriate actions when user performs the changes in his workspace. Though when other users change the model file, and the new synced file is obtained in other workspace, I get only notification that xml file was modified. What exact model changes were done is not received.

Things work fine if user closes and open the project.Though this is not the right solution. I tried doing resource.unload followed by resource.load.This didn't make any difference. How can I achieve the desired result programmaticaly?

Answer (score 0):

[EMF Compare](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF_Compare) should be able to help you in comparing two files, but I'm not sure if it integrates well with SCMs.